# Add row num not working in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to add `rownum` in my below oracle query but it is giving me error as

> ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function

Here is my query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () AS sr_no, pn.lease_num, hz.party_name,
   flt.location_code, flt.office flat_no, NULL action, la.no_of_days,
   NULL remarks, flt.location_id flat_id, pn.lease_id
 FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all la,
   pn_leases_all pn,
   (SELECT *
      FROM pn_locations_all flat
     WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN flat.active_start_date AND flat.active_end_date) bld,
   (SELECT *
      FROM pn_locations_all flat
     WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN flat.active_start_date AND flat.active_end_date) flr,
   (SELECT *
      FROM pn_locations_all flat
     WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN flat.active_start_date AND flat.active_end_date) flt,
   pn_properties_all prop,
   hz_parties hz,
   apps.hz_cust_accounts sc1
WHERE la.lease_id = pn.lease_id
 AND pn.location_id = flt.location_id
 AND flt.parent_location_id = flr.location_id
 AND flr.parent_location_id = bld.location_id
 AND bld.property_id = prop.property_id
 AND pn.customer_id = sc1.cust_account_id
 AND sc1.party_id = hz.party_id
 AND la.type_of_booking = 50
 AND prop.property_id = '1'
 AND bld.location_id = '1309'
```

kindly help what is wrong

**I am using ORACLE**

Comment: Try to reduce the SQL to the absolute minimum, that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: @slartidan: yup, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See documentation for [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm). You need to write something like:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY la.type_of_booking ORDER BY la.lease_id)
FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all la
```

or

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY la.lease_id)
FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_leases_all la
```

Comment: let me try second one